# SwiftUI navigationLink not working after dismissing destination from the stack

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

I haven't noticed this before, so it may be a bug with the new release.

When I click on a NavigationLink, everything works as expected.  Then I can click the back button (which I have done with the default back button as well as a custom back button) and it still works.  If I try to click the same NavigationLink again, it does not trigger the destination.  I can click on a different NavigationLink, and it will work, and when I go back the first link is functional again.  Only the last link is unavailable.

This seems to be the case in lists, forms, and free navigation links.

Has anyone encountered this functionality? Is there a fix for it?

Working on Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Navigation scheme is V0->V1->V2. First time all work fine. But if I back from V2 to V1 NavigationLink stops work and come go from V1 to V2. After back to V0 navigation again works fine.

Comment: I face the same issue 

Comment: Check out my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933501/4067700).
Is it works for you mark your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of searching and testing, this appears to be a bug specific to the simulator in the new release.  When running the app on my phone it works perfectly.  Hopefully it is fixed soon, but for now I can run testing on the phone.

Comment: Thanks! Debugging for awhile before landed here.

Comment: I'll also add that this was a bug throughout most of the 13.3 betas

Comment: Check out my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933501/4067700)

Comment: Same problem exist in the Xcode 11.3 in the preview and showing error message.  But when we build the application its working fine in the simulator some times.

Comment: On the simulator it let's you click the button again if you refresh the view...definitely a bug for Apple to fix though