# How to make Image Clickable in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var isActive : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("home-img")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fill)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .overlay(Image("round")
                 .resizable()
                 .frame(width: 350, height: 350 , alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Image("girl-img")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
            )
            .overlay(Image("video")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(y: -200)
                .padding(.bottom, -70)
            ).onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SelecteImageView(), isActive: self.$isActive) {
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

What I want to do is when I tap on `Image("Video")` it should redirect me to a new screen using `NavigationView`. Normally, with button, it redirects to a new screen, but here the problem is that the image is in overlay. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your Image Views inside the `NavigationLink` `label`.
The `navigationLink` acts like Button and it gets the default button style with blue color. So change the default button style to plain using the bellow modifier:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var isActive : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: SelecteImageView(), isActive: self.$isActive) {
            VStack {
                Image("home-img") //.renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                    .clipped() //Here shows your Image only inside the frame
                    .overlay(Image("round") //.renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 350 , alignment: .center))
                    .overlay(Image("girl-img") //.renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                )
                    .overlay(Image("video") //.renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .offset(y: -200)
                        .padding(.bottom, -70)
                )
            }
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you can give your Image views `.renderingMode(.original)` modifier if you are only using Images, and remove `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` from above code.

Comment: It is working for me but it is working only one time redirection.when I come back home screen and again want to go in redirection screen it didn't work. @FRIDDAY

Comment: this make whole screen clickble not image only.

Comment: @SohanConceptioni It makes the whole screen clickable because you gave your image `.resizable()` and `aspectRatio(contentMode:.fill)` modifiers. It filled your Image to the given frame but the remain is still there. you need to remove it using `.clipped()`. I update the answer.

Comment: @SohanConceptioni About your first comment, I don't have this problem on my iPhone. If you still have this problem, its seems like a bug and  it is discussing here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279176/navigationlink-works-only-for-once

Comment: Additionally, If you wanna be able to click on a specific area you need to rewrite your code and use `ZStack` instead of `.overlay`. In this code the whole frame of your `VStack` is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Please add tap gesture over here

```
    struct Contentview: View {
    @State var isNavigate :Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()) {
                    Image("Birthday")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200 , alignment: .center)
                    .overlay(Image("round")
                             .resizable()
                             .frame(width: 350, height: 350 , alignment: .center)
                        )
                        .overlay(Image("girl-img")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edit my code. I put navigationview but it didn't work.

Comment: @SohanConceptioni i just edited my answer please check it. and let me know if you face any issue

Comment: @SohanConceptioni have you checked it?

Comment: but where i have to put tapgesture?

Comment: You don't need to add tap gesture just add navigation link in vstack

Comment: then i am getting blank screen with blue color as home screen